# Does MPMediaItemPropertyIsCloudItem require iOS 6 Runtime?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6

iOS SDK 6 introduced the new property constant `MPMediaItemPropertyIsCloudItem`. I understand that we don't get access to this constant unless you build against the iOS 6 SDK, but will code reading this property still return a valid result if the user is running iOS 5?

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaItem_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/MPMediaItemPropertyIsCloudItem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out (unsurprisingly I guess), `MPMediaItemPropertyIsCloudItem` constant does not exist until iOS 6 Runtime. You must guard against referencing this by checking if the address of the constant is NULL.

```
if(&MPMediaItemPropertyIsCloudItem == NULL)
{
     //do pre-iOS 6 stuff here
}
else
{
     NSNumber * isCloud = [mediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyIsCloudItem];
}
```